# Java How can I put an image on a rectangle

Tags: java, image, import, rectangles

This is the code

```
 player = createEntity(400, 600, 40, 60, Color.BLUE);

private Node createEntity(int x, int y, int w, int h, Color color) {
    Rectangle entity = new Rectangle(w, h);
    entity.setTranslateX(x);
    entity.setTranslateY(y);
    entity.setFill(color);

    gameRoot.getChildren().add(entity);
    return entity;

}
```

I'm not sure how to put an image to my player, any thoughts?

Comment: That will depend on how things are painted, but essentially, you would paint one then the other at the same location

Comment: You could also paint the rectangle directly to the image, but, again, that comes down to knowing more then you're telling us

Answer (score 3):

> Java How can I put an image on a rectangle

My suggestion (if this is Swing) is not to use a Rectangle, or else use Rectangle but as part of a larger solution.

Instead I'd create a logical class, perhaps called Entity, that has a position, an image, and a draw method that accepts a Graphics parameter draws its image at whatever position needed, and then create Entity objects. Then within my JPanel's paintComponent method, I'd iterate through all the Entities created, calling their draw method.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you'll want to use [active rendering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/rendering.html/). This'll prevent you from having all sorts of problems related to refreshing the display, and Java's `BufferStrategy` automatically handles multi-buffering for you, assuming you request more than one buffer.

---

Now that you're sure the screen gets updated, when rendering, you can draw a rectangle with a `java.awt.Graphics` object using the `drawRect` method. If you would like to fill this rectangle, use `fillRect`. The `Graphics` object draws everything in a pre-defined colour. If you would like to change colour, you can call `setColor`. This method requires a `java.awt.Color` object as an argument, which allows you to define all possible 64-bit transparent colours using one of the constructors. It also has a few predefined colours, like `Color.RED`, which is `0xFF0000`.

I recommend you explore all the methods `Graphics` has to offer, and maybe even look into `Graphics2D`, which supports a few extra things. Note that most `Graphics` objects can be cast to `Graphics2D`, but if you're not sure, you might either want to look into Java's source code (there is an `src.zip` inside the JDK installation) or use an `instanceof` check. As a matter of fact, `Graphics2D` supports drawing shapes like your `Rectangle` using the `drawShape` or `fillShape` method.

---

For those of you who are curious, `0xFF0000` is a way of formatting colours. It is RGB encoded into hexadecimal (`0xRRGGBB`). It's also commonly represented `#FF0000` in other languages, like CSS (Cascading Style Sheet, used for easily formatting HTML documents)